# jquery 'attribute contains' selector with a dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that i have a variable `questionId` which is an integer, and i want to find `tr` elements that have the fragment (`"question_"+questionId`) in their id.  How can i do this?  I thought that i would be able to do it with the jquery ['attribute contains' selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

Eg, this works, for a non-dynamic value,

```
$("tr[id*='quiz_question_7674']")
```

but, i can't work out how to plug the variable value in there.  This doesn't work for example:

```
questionId = 7674;
$("tr[id*='quiz_question_'+questionId]")
```

Any ideas anyone?  Is there a better way than 'attribute contains' to do it?  I have the feeling i'm missing something obvious.

thanks, max

EDIT - SOLVED. doh, i am indeed missing something obvious.  I keep forgetting that it's just a string, nothing more:

$("tr[id*='quiz_question_"+questionId+"']")

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have error:

```
var questionId = 7674;
$("tr[id*='quiz_question_" + questionId + "']");
```

Notes:

1. Please use var to declare variables.
2. questionId is a variable. It is not part of the selector. You should concatenate questionId to the string.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, you almost had it:

```
var selector = "tr[id*='quiz_question_" + questionId + "']";
$(selector)
```